# how to save and read xml file into one database table column which is xml data type

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have linq database table with 3 columns one use for stored xml file

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Txml(
   brRacuna int NULL,
   korisnickoime varchar(50) NULL,
   xmldata xml NULL
   )
```

I try this to save xml file into column datatype xml

```
   XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Nikolic\Documents\Visual Studio
   2013\Projects\MojSajt\MojSajt\korpaxml.xml");
       var query = from r in document.Descendants("proizvod")

                   select new
                   {
                       naziv = r.Element("naziv").Value,
                       kolicina = r.Element("kolicina").Value,
                       cena = r.Element("cena").Value,
                       iznos = r.Element("iznos").Value
                   };
       Txml nov = new Txml();
       nov.xmldata =(XElement)query;
       north.Txmls.InsertOnSubmit(nov);
       north.SubmitChanges();
```

It dosen't work I need to save and read xml file into one column which is xml data type using c# and linq(datacontext)

Comment: *It doesn't wok*, what is happening? error message?

Comment: @miroslav No one can help without knowing the problem. What do you mean by *doesn't work*? If you got error, what was the error message exactly? what is `xmldata` type *in C#*? (I know it is XML in database, but in C# model?)

Comment: xmldata is column in linq database table which have xml data type

Comment: As I said, I know it is xml data type in database, but what is the type in C#? what you get if you hover on `xmldata` in this line : `nov.xmldata =(XElement)query;`

Comment: in this line nov.xmldata=(XElement)query I got error

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType0`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.

Comment: Try `nov.xmldata = document.Root` and see what you get now...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `XmlDocument` instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

You could do something like

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourFile);
nov.xmldata = doc;
```

Comment: XDocument is a lot nicer to work with and is the recommended choice.

Comment: I need to read xml file from linq database table from column which type is xml data type and store to xdocument